# Displaying data group wise

Tags: mysql

In mysql database, my table has following entries:

```
----------------------------------------
user_id        date           subject
----------------------------------------
id8771       2018-06-25      English
id8772       2018-06-25      French
id8773       2018-06-25      spanish 
id8774       2018-06-24      English
id8775       2018-06-24      English
id8776       2018-06-24      Spanish
id8777       2018-06-24      Hindi
id8778       2018-06-22      Sanskrit
id8779       2018-06-22      French
id8780       2018-06-19      Sanskrit
id8781       2018-06-19      English
id8781       2018-06-19      English
id8781       2018-06-19      Sanskrit
id8781       2018-06-19      Spanish
```

In my Applications I want to display data datewise. like displaying data of previous 30 days.
Like i want to display data of last 2 days, it should be this:

```
----------------------------------------
user_id        date           subject
----------------------------------------
id8771       2018-06-25      English
id8772       2018-06-25      French
id8773       2018-06-25      spanish 
id8774       2018-06-24      English
id8775       2018-06-24      English
id8776       2018-06-24      Spanish
id8777       2018-06-24      Hindi
```

Is there any such query in mysql?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I've done it programmatically. fetched current date/month/year, then increased the date by 29 days, put them in array and fetched the data of all the 30 days that match with items in the array. but its too lengthy. I'm looking for a simple query which can work this out.

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY, which is likely to prove problematic in due course.

Comment: primary key is there on user_id. mistakenly i repeated the user_id. sorry.

Comment: Luckily, there's an edit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select values by using

```
SELECT ... WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Usually BETWEEN is the same for >=, but it's more clearer for understanding and formatting

Comment: what if within the period of 30 days few days have no entries. how will i be able to collect the data of previous 30 days ? i don't want to count those days which have no entries.

Comment: You can change your strategy and select only a finite number of records (use LIMIT 10 for example) over the month. And don't forgot to use ORDER BY for date column to select the latest

Answer (score 2):

use date_sub(now(), interval 2 day) to find previous two day's date

```
select * from tablename where date>=date_sub(now(), interval 2 day)
```

Answer (score 1):

All records whose date is greater than two days ago:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```